# How does the contoller action syntax in url_for work in Mojo?

Tags: perl, mojolicious

From the [docs here](https://mojolicious.org/perldoc/Mojolicious/Plugin/DefaultHelpers.txt)

```
  %= url_for 'named', controller => 'bar', action => 'baz'

Alias for L<Mojolicious::Controller/"url_for">.

  %= url_for('/index.html')->query(foo => 'bar')
```

How can `url_for 'named', controller => 'bar', action => 'baz'` be an alias for `url_for('/index.html')->query(foo => 'bar')` when the first one doesn't even contain `'foo'`?

Comment: It isn't. The helper is an alias, not the example.